# Can Redis lost data?

Tags: caching, redis

I haven't strong knowledge in Redis, so I need help!

As I know Redis store data in memory and sometimes does dump to hard drive.

Does it mean if Redis process fall down for some reason, I'll lose all my data?

If it is, what can I do for save data till process will be restored?

Thanks!

Comment: `Does it mean if Redis process fall down for some reason, I'll lose all my data?` Yes. `If it is, what can I do for save data till process will be restored?` Don't use redis for persistent data storage.

Answer (score 0):

http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Redis comes with AOF (append only file) and RDB (snapshotting) persistence options, it also have configurable param to keep the data loss very minimal.

If you configure every 1 sec snapshot or every event one by one write to AOF file then it might affect the performance.